# HttpForbiddenError when trying to access Google Cloud Storage from Apache Beam

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam-io

I've trying to simple access with Apache Beam to Google Cloud storage from  Compute Engine VM. 
Sure, I've set up default application login with command 
gcloud auth application-default login
and add access to the storage for compute engine service account. 
I've run the pipeline with DirectRunner and got the Error: 
apache_beam.io.filesystem.BeamIOError: Match operation failed with exceptions {'gs://{THIS MY BUCKETNAME}/source/sales_transactions.csv': HttpForbiddenError()}

```py
#import print library
import logging

#import apache beam library
import apache_beam as beam

#import pipeline options.
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import  PipelineOptions

#Create a pipeline
plOps = beam.Pipeline(options=PipelineOptions())

#--------------------------------------------------
# 1.Read from a text file.
#--------------------------------------------------

#Read the file from Google Cloud Storage
transactions = ( plOps 
                | 'Read Transaction CSV'
                    >> beam.io.ReadFromText('gs://{THIS MY BUCKETNAME}/data/sales_transactions.csv')
                )

printSize(transactions,'Raw Transactions')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah! I solved it.
Just recreate default application credential - really I don't know what was wrong with them. I've made it unambiguously. Otherwise folder /root/.config/gcloud hadn't existed. But something happened with credentials.

So, how to solve it:
1. sudo su
2. drop folder 
/root/.config/gcloud
3. Run again gcloud auth application-default login

Be lucky!

Answer (score 0):

I've partially resolved the issue - reading ok. 
I've login by root with sudo su on DEVELOPER MACHINE and Apache Beam got access to read file from GS. 
But when I try to write into GS bucket like this

```
#Write output to a text file
( custTypeCount | 'Write to GS Text'
        >> beam.io.WriteToText('gs://{MY BUCKET NAME}/output/customertype-summary.txt')
)
```

script got error:

```
RuntimeError: HttpForbiddenError: HttpError accessing <https://www.googleapis.com/resumable/upload/storage/v1/b/{MY BUCKET NAME}/o?uploadType=resumable&alt=json&name=output%2Fbeam-temp-customertype-summary.txt-7bea505ad0bf11e9b69c42010a800002%2F55a9057e-18e5-4171-9db4-9e55601b2a8d.customertype-summary.txt>: response: <{'status': '403', 'content-length': '208', 'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin', 'server': 'UploadServer', 'x-guploader-uploadid': 'AEnB2Upo4RBzVV1S51_uWhcCiK_uK_iOSRAdAb8HWMhxznaPr0JcHKWxKDLwHbtTIYvHuMjyESV4dZqAfN3TaWYMqr5gQeypcQ', 'date': 'Fri, 06 Sep 2019 16:00:44 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'www-authenticate': 'Bearer realm="https://accounts.google.com/"'}>, content <{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
    "message": "Insufficient Permission"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Insufficient Permission"
 }
}
> [while running 'Write to GS Text/Write/WriteImpl/WriteBundles']
```

And I haven't any idea what permission should I add